# Reutilização de funções em Python

Tags: python-2.7

Sou iniciante em programação e estou com a seguinte situação:

- Tenho uma classe chamada TESTE. Dentro dessa classe possui a função ALEATÓRIO.
- Tenho uma segunda classe chamada VERIFICAR. Dentro dessa classe possui a função VERIFICA.
- Desejo que a saída da função TESTE.ALEATÓRIO seja aproveitada na função VERIFICAR.VERIFICA.
- No código abaixo toda vez que executo a função VERIFICAR.VERIFICA ela chama novamente a função TESTE.ALEATÓRIO, o que acaba me trazendo um novo valor.
- Como faço para REUTILIZAR a saída da função TESTE.ALEATÓRIO?

=========

```
import random

class teste():
    def __init__(self, x = 0):
        self.x = x

def aleatorio(self):
    a = random.randint(0,100)
    return a

class verificar():
    def __init__(self, y = 0):
        self.y = y

    def verifica(self):
        b = teste().aleatorio()
        return b

print (teste().aleatorio())
print (verificar().verifica())
```

==========

Antecipadamente, agradeço a todos que se disporem em ajudar.

Comment: Você quer que seja gerado apenas um valor aleatório e seja utilizado nas duas chamadas?

Comment: Quero que o valor aleatório, gerado na função TESTE.ALEATÓRIO, também seja utilizado na função VERIFICAR.VERIFICA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

```
import random

class teste():
    def __init__(self, x = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.aleatorio()

    def aleatorio(self):
        self.a = random.randint(0,100)
        return self.a

class verificar():
    def __init__(self, y = 0):
        self.y = y

    def verifica(self):
        b = teste()
        return b.a
```

Se precisar chamar `aleatorio()` de novo, dá pra fazer o seguinte:

```
class verificar():
    def __init__(self, y = 0):
        self.y = y
        self.teste = teste()

    def verifica(self, chamar_de_novo = False):
        if (chamar_de_novo):
            self.teste.aleatorio()
        return self.teste.a
```

Note que aqui:

```
print (verificar().verifica())
```

Você está usando um objeto `verifica` diferente daqui:

```
print (teste().aleatorio())
```

Por isso que o valor não se mantém. Você pode fazer, por exemplo, `verificar` receber um objeto `teste` para pelo menos manter o número aleatório gerado:

```
v = verificar()
teste = teste()
teste.aleatorio()
v.teste = teste
```

Comment: quando eu executo, dá o erro " TypeError: aleatorio() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"

Fiz algo errado?

Comment: Erro de indentação meu. Veja minha edição, por favor.

Comment: Corrigi a identação, agora dá o erro: " NameError: global name 'aleatorio' is not defined"

Comment: Desculpe, não testei este código. Editei novamente.

Comment: Sem problemas. Estou aqui para aprender. Veja, quando "printei" as funções. Veja a saída: 28, 56. Queria que a função da classe VERIFICAR.VERIFICA, retorna-se 28 também
Desculpa incomodar, sou novato.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tem razão. Vou editar mais uma vez.

Comment: @Danilo Do jeito em que está, não tem como você manter os números. Coloquei mais algumas sugestões.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58840/discussion-between-danilo-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Comment: Não vou poder te ajudar agora. Estou com uns candidatos agora de manhã pra avaliar. Veja [este chat aqui](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: Consegui. Cigano!
Obrigado pela paciência!! Muito Obrigado!